# Redefine options in TikZ-UML sequence diagrams

Tags: tikz-uml

I have several `TikZ-UML` sequence diagrams and mostly I always set the options `dt=5` and `padding=3` for all `umlcall`. Is it possible to set these two variables for these values as default?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlbasicobject{B}
        \umlbasicobject[x=6]{C}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=msg1, return={r0, r1}, dt=4, padding=3]{C}{B}
        \end{umlcall}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=callback, return={ok}, dt=5, padding=3]{B}{C}
        \end{umlcall}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=msg2, return=r2, dt=5, padding=3]{C}{B}
        \end{umlcall}

      \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `umlcall` environment does

```
\pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd,%
   dt/.initial={tikzumlEmpty},%
   padding/.initial=2,%
   [...]
```

so there's no way to pass different initial values except correcting the environment's definition. Here's a way with `xpatch`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\umlcall}
  {dt/.initial={tikzumlEmpty}}
  {dt/.initial=5}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\umlcall}
  {padding/.initial=2}
  {padding/.initial=3}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlbasicobject{B}
        \umlbasicobject[x=6]{C}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=msg1, return={r0, r1}, dt=4, padding=3]{C}{B}
        \end{umlcall}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=callback, return={ok}, dt=5, padding=3]{B}{C}
        \end{umlcall}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=msg2, return=r2, dt=5, padding=3]{C}{B}
        \end{umlcall}

      \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlbasicobject{B}
        \umlbasicobject[x=6]{C}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=msg1, return={r0, r1}, dt=4]{C}{B}
        \end{umlcall}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=callback, return={ok}]{B}{C}
        \end{umlcall}

        \begin{umlcall}[op=msg2, return=r2]{C}{B}
        \end{umlcall}

      \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I typeset the original call and the new one where the values are not specified in order to see they're identical.

[image]

Comment: Is `\ddt` a non-existent command to cause an error on purpose when `xpatch` fails? (I couldn't find a specific definition on the documentation.) Why is not used when patching `dt`?

Comment: @user3371321 Yes, I use it to get warned if the patch fails, it's supposed to be undefined. Usually I remove it after testing, but this time I forgot doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I created a new environment, `Umlcall` which has your desired defaults.  I changed up your MWE parameters a bit to show that one can override the defaults, and that the method works without any optional argument, as well.  The defaults are defined in the macro `\umldefaults`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\newcommand\umldefaults{dt=5, padding=3, }
\newenvironment{Umlcall}[3][]{\expandafter\umlcall\expandafter[\umldefaults #1]{#2}{#3}}%
  {\endumlcall}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlbasicobject{B}
        \umlbasicobject[x=6]{C}

        \begin{Umlcall}[op=msg1, return={r0, r1}, dt=7, padding=5]{C}{B}
        \end{Umlcall}

        \begin{Umlcall}[op=callback, return={ok}]{B}{C}
        \end{Umlcall}

        \begin{Umlcall}[op=msg2, return=r2]{C}{B}
        \end{Umlcall}

        \begin{Umlcall}{C}{B}
        \end{Umlcall}

      \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're right. tikz-uml offers a way to define global default value thanks to the command `\tikzumlset` but I only activated it for drawing purpose, namely draw, fill and text options of each available UML element. I added the possibility to define global default value for quite every option of every element. This will be available soon in the new release of tikz-uml.